# How to query values by line with a join?

Tags: sql, join

given the two tables and values:

```
Tables
People- Columns: [ID]PK Name
Field - Columns: [ID FieldName]PK FieldValue

Values
People
ID Name
1  Mary
2  John
3  Tony

Field
ID FieldName  FieldValue
1  Age        20
1  Country    USA
2  Age        21
2  Country    USA
3  Age        20
3  Country    USA
```

I would like a query that gives me the names of the people from USA AND have 20 years old. The result should be Mary and Tony.

```
SELECT name FROM people p
INNER JOIN field f ON f.ID = f.ID
WHERE
(FieldName = 'Age' AND FieldValue= '20') OR
(FieldName = 'Country' AND FieldValue= 'USA'));
```

The problem with that query is the "OR" between the where clauses. I will get the 3 people, instead of only Mary and Tony. If I use an AND, none result is return.

Do you have some tips?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check a possible typo on this line `INNER JOIN field f ON f.ID = f.ID`.  It should be `f.ID = p.ID`

Comment: I beg you to change the name of the table "Field" to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT name
FROM people p
JOIN field fAge ON p.ID = fAge.ID
   AND fAge.FieldName = 'Age'
JOIN field fCountry ON p.ID = fCountry.ID
   AND fCountry.FieldName = 'Country'
WHERE fAge.FieldValue = '20'
AND fCountry.FieldValue = 'USA'
```

Thereby treating the Country and Age data essentially as separate tables.  As it seems that the `field` table is used to store different types of data.

It might be useful to have different database `Views` on this table for each type of data.  This will further simplify the above query.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done here, unfortunately, is implemented the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) antipattern. (Antipattern is a fancy word for "something that's usually a bad idea.") It's generally counter to SQL best practices to have a "Field" table like yours, which is why it has an antipattern named after it. "Entity" refers to your ID column (or, by association, a Person record), "Attribute" corresponds to FieldName, and "Value" to FieldValue.

For more information, take a look at [this excellent set of slides](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back/16) (this should link directly to the section on EAV; if not, skip to slide 16).

The solution is to refactor your database so that Age and Country are fields in your People table. Then a far simpler query will be possible: `SELECT name FROM people WHERE Age = 20 AND Country = 'USA';`

Comment: I know Jordan. Unfortunately that is the model I need to deal with. Legacy tables without possibility to change. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

You don't say whether you considered and rejected the "standard" design that would Name, Age, and Country in a single table.  That would allow substantially easier querying and also type and range protection for the Age values as well as FK/PK protection for the Country values.

If you do have a positive reason to use the Key/Value approach, then you have three choices for your query:

1. Join the Key/Value table in the query one time for each term you're searching for (see Philip's answer, above).
2. Use WHERE EXISTS conditions:

   ```
   SELECT Name FROM People WHERE
      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Field WHERE ID = People.ID AND FieldName = 'Country' AND Fieldvalue = 'USA')
      AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Field WHERE ID = People.ID AND FieldName = 'Age' AND Fieldvalue = '20')
   ```
3. Use some kind of INTERSECT or SUBTRACT operator if supported in your dialect of SQL.